# XOR in java with negative bytes

Tags: java, binary, xor, twos-complement

```
byte b = -0b0101^-0b0100;
System.out.println("Outputs "+b);
//Outputs 7
```

Why does this output 7 (`0b111`) when I was expecting 1 (`0b001`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Negative numbers are calculated according to "two's complement" arithmetic.

```
-0b0101 = NOT(0000 0101) + 1 = 1111 1010 + 1 = 1111 1011
-0b0100 = NOT(0000 0100) + 1 = 1111 1011 + 1 = 1111 1100
```

If you XOR these you get:

```
0000 0111 = 7
```

Answer (score 0):

For presenting negative numbers in binary we use "Two's complement"

This is how you get negative binary numbers in java, check this link:
[How are integers internally represented at a bit level in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422259/how-are-integers-internally-represented-at-a-bit-level-in-java)

Then you get:
-5 in binary is 11111011
-4 in binary is 11111100
                --------
                00000111 = which is 7. That is why output is 7, hope it helps.