# Why are these two different representations (dec vs. hex) of integers different in Java?

Tags: java, hex, decimal

Say I have two integers, one in decimal the other in hexadecimal:

```
int myInt01 = 0xc7d23020;
int myInt02 = 3352440864;
```

The are both the same number, but when I try to assign the decimal integer to a variable in Java, I get the error:

```
error: integer number too large: 3352440864
```

But when I assign the hexadecimal integer to a variable in Java, everything works as it should.

Why is it this way?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils - really ?

Comment: No, I made a mistake. Didn't get the c down.

Comment: If you google Hex to Decimal converter on Google and stick in 0xc7d23020, it will spit out 3352440864, and vice versa.

Comment: Have you checked the value of that hex variable. It isn't `3352440864` it's `-942526432`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `0xc7d23020` is interpreted as `-942526432` which is a valid `int` value, while `3352440864` is clearly a wrong `int` value because it's higher than the limit `2147483647`;

Comment: why is interpreted as -942526432

Comment: I'd add something about Java `int`s being in two's compliment.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is intended behavior: The binary representation of this number has the most significant bit set, in a 32 bit datatype. Since in Java `int` is a signed datatype, the most significant bit is reserved for the sign of the number. Thus, the number is not a valid positive number. This is what the compiler is telling you. However, since it is a valid negative integer, it does not complain when you assign it using the hex-representation.

You can try assigning a number that would need more than 32 bits to an integer variable using the hex-representation. This will lead to a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

The max value that a `int` variable can hold is `2147483647`. That's why it is giving that error. You can check that out yourself by doing this:    `System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE);`

To find out the minimum value that a int variable can hold `System.out.println(Integer.MIN_VALUE);`

Comment: Yes, that's the reason! You need to use a `long` variable to hold that number, not an int.

Comment: So, why does the Hex value work but not the decimal value?

Comment: in fact the number specified is negative

Comment: This answer almost answers the question.

Comment: @JonnyHenly Not really. Why does Java let me assign the base 16 but not the base 10?

Comment: @JonnyHenly according to this website http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter 0xc7d23020 = 3352440864

Comment: @PabloPazos according to this website http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter 0xc7d23020 = 3352440864

Comment: What's the two's compliment of that hex value?

Comment: @Brian I thought the question was why can't I hold that big number in an int variable. So I answered accordingly. I don't know the answer to the actual question sorry :P

Comment: @JonnyHenly I don't remember I took those classes long time ago. But is that website wrong?

Comment: No it's right for positive hex values, but a negative integer can be represented in bits differently.

Comment: It seems on Java 8 Integer can represent unsigned ints, but he didn't specified the java version, ref https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html IMO that number being positive or negative, depends on if it is signed or unsigned.

Comment: The page you provided show dec to hex conversion in general, that is not how Java represents ints internally, this is a good ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422259/how-are-integers-internally-represented-at-a-bit-level-in-java