# flip all bits for a Long (in java)

Tags: bit-manipulation, long-integer, unsigned-integer

Curious why this works

```
public long flip(long n) {
    long finalResult = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        finalResult = finalResult | (1L << i);
    }
    return n ^ finalResult;
}
```

but this doesn't

```
public long flip(long n) {
    long finalResult = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        finalResult = finalResult | (1 << i);
    }
    return n ^ finalResult;
}
```

I know that finalResult '11111111111111111111111111111111' will be -1 (and maybe that causes an issue) but i'm still not sure why it causes issues when simply flipping bits in n.

Comment: Note that as written, both functions will do the same thing -- flip the lower 32 bits of value, leaving the upper 32 bits unchanged.  Maybe you meant to write `i < 64` in the loop tests?  In which case the first would flip all bits, and the second would just flip the lower 32 bits.

Comment: Java and C# follow the same rules for the [left shift operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/left-shift-operator) - "*If the first operand is an int or uint (32-bit quantity), the shift count is given by the low-order five bits of the second operand. That is, the actual shift count is 0 to 31 bits.*"

Comment: @ChrisDodd - wouldn't the second flip the lower 32 bits *twice* and leave the input `n` unchanged?

Comment: @WaiHaLee: no, becuase the loop uses `|` not `^`...

Comment: Since [Java signed values are defined as two's-complement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13422442/1270789), `return ~(n - 1);` is all that is needed?

Comment: @ChrisDodd i meant all 1s would be -1. Fixed question.